# SVG inside a tag is cut off on IE11

Tags: css, internet-explorer, svg

I have the following markup:

```
<a class="logo" href="/" style="
    display: inline-block;
"><img src="/img/logo.svg"></a>
```

only on IE 11 it seems like the img is pushed down and cut off.

.logo CSS

```
border-radius: 0;
float: left !important;
background-color: transparent;
margin-top: -10px;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
```

and on the img I only have the width set to 130px.

Comment: Why has it been closed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link and also the image are `inline-block` , that creates a lot of space due to line-height. Use a reset or set the outline/border to 0 for both links and image and set the line-height to 1 for these two elements.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of ways to handle this in case anyone else experiences this issue.

1. Give img a min-width and min-height of a value higher than the width. In your case it's 130px so 131px? You'll have to play around to see how many pixels are being clipped. -- this is specific for IE11

or

2. Give img a min-width and min-height of a value of 100% and position it relative to the containing element - .logo class. If you want the img to live inside of the containing element, you'll need to give it a width that is larger than the img. -- this is better for cross browser support.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm afraid, neither of those options worked for me